# XSLT - Grouping Elements after Index value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm writing a XSLT that needs to output certain data elements but into fixed length containers. While typically the source data will contain fewer elements than the fixed length, there is potential for the source data to contain more elements than the fixed length. When the latter occurs, I need to output the elements individually to a certain index, then group the remaining siblings based on a property so I can use concatenation and summation on the groups. I'm able to achieve all of this with the exception of the grouping of siblings after a given index value.

Below is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve. Assume the fixed length of the container is `5` and the only `Type` values to be outputted are `1` and `2`, omitting `3`.

Sample input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Company>
  <Locations>
    <Location>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Shoppers>
        <Shopper>
          <Products>
            <Product>
              <Amount>5.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>A</Name>
              <Type>1</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>10.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>B</Name>
              <Type>2</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>15.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>C</Name>
              <Type>3</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>20.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>D</Name>
              <Type>1</Type>
            </Product>
          </Products>
        </Shopper>
        <Shopper>
          <Products>
            <Product>
              <Amount>25.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>E</Name>
              <Type>2</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>30.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>F</Name>
              <Type>1</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>35.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>G</Name>
              <Type>2</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>40.00</Amount>
              <Id>1</Id>
              <Name>H</Name>
              <Type>1</Type>
            </Product>
          </Products>
        </Shopper>
      </Shoppers>
    </Location>
    <Location>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Shoppers>
        <Shopper>
          <Products>
            <Product>
              <Amount>5.00</Amount>
              <Id>2</Id>
              <Name>I</Name>
              <Type>A</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>10.00</Amount>
              <Id>2</Id>
              <Name>J</Name>
              <Type>B</Type>
            </Product>
          </Products>
        </Shopper>
        <Shopper>
          <Products>
            <Product>
              <Amount>25.00</Amount>
              <Id>2</Id>
              <Name>K</Name>
              <Type>A</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>30.00</Amount>
              <Id>2</Id>
              <Name>L</Name>
              <Type>B</Type>
            </Product>
            <Product>
              <Amount>35.00</Amount>
              <Id>2</Id>
              <Name>M</Name>
              <Type>B</Type>
            </Product>
          </Products>
        </Shopper>
      </Shoppers>
    </Location>
  </Locations>
</Company>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl customCode"  xmlns:customCode="urn:customCode">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

  <xsl:key name="product-distinct" match="Product" use="concat(Id,Type)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Locations>
      <xsl:for-each select="Company/Locations/Location">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="Id"/>
        <!--Ideally, I would like to use a variable as to not repeat the same XPath throughout the code to simplify any necessary changes-->
        <xsl:variable name="productList" select="Shoppers/Shopper/Products/Product[Type != '3']"/>
        <Location>
          <Products>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="count($productList) &gt; 5">
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="count($productList[generate-id() = generate-id(key('product-distinct', concat($id,Type))[1])]) = 2">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$productList[position() &lt; 4]">
                      <xsl:call-template name="Product">
                        <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="Amount"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="productName" select="Name"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="Type"/>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="count($productList[position() &gt; 3][generate-id() = generate-id(key('product-distinct', concat($id,Type))[1])]) = 2">
                        <xsl:for-each select="$productList[position() &gt; 3][generate-id() = generate-id(key('product-distinct', concat($id,Type))[1])]">
                          <xsl:variable name="keyGroup" select="key('product-distinct', concat($id,Type))"/>
                          <xsl:call-template name="Product">
                            <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="sum($keyGroup/Amount)"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="productName" select="$keyGroup"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$keyGroup/Type"/>
                          </xsl:call-template>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="Product">
                          <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="$productList[4]/Amount"/>
                          <xsl:with-param name="productName" select="$productList[4]/Name"/>
                          <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$productList[4]/Type"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="Product">
                          <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="sum($productList[position() &gt; 4]/Amount)"/>
                          <xsl:with-param name="productName">
                            <xsl:call-template name="CombineProductNames">
                              <xsl:with-param name="products" select="$productList[position() &gt; 4]"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                          </xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$productList[5]/Type"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$productList[position() &lt; 5]">
                      <xsl:call-template name="Product">
                        <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="Amount"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="productName" select="Name"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="type" select="Type"/>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:call-template name="Product">
                      <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="sum($productList[position() &gt; 4]/Amount)"/>
                      <xsl:with-param name="productName">
                        <xsl:call-template name="CombineProductNames">
                          <xsl:with-param name="products" select="$productList[position() &gt; 4]"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:with-param>
                      <xsl:with-param name="type" select="$productList[5]/Type"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:for-each select="$productList">
                  <xsl:call-template name="Product">
                    <xsl:with-param name="amount" select="Amount"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="productName" select="Name"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="type" select="Type"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </Products>
        </Location>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Locations>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Product">
    <xsl:param name="amount"/>
    <xsl:param name="productName"/>
    <xsl:param name="type"/>
    <Product>
      <xsl:attribute name="Amount">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($amount, '0.00')"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="$productName"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Type">
        <xsl:value-of select="$type"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </Product>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CombineProductNames">
    <xsl:param name="products"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$products/Name">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Locations>
  <Location>
    <Products>
      <Product Amount="5.00" Name="A" Type="1" />
      <Product Amount="10.00" Name="B" Type="2" />
      <Product Amount="20.00" Name="D" Type="1" />
      <Product Amount="25.00" Name="E" Type="2" />
      <Product Amount="105.00" Name="F, G, H" Type="1" />
    </Products>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Products>
      <Product Amount="5.00" Name="I" Type="A" />
      <Product Amount="10.00" Name="J" Type="B" />
      <Product Amount="25.00" Name="K" Type="A" />
      <Product Amount="30.00" Name="L" Type="B" />
      <Product Amount="35.00" Name="M" Type="B" />
    </Products>
  </Location>
</Locations>
```

Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Locations>
  <Location>
    <Products>
      <Product Amount="5.00" Name="A" Type="1" />
      <Product Amount="10.00" Name="B" Type="2" />
      <Product Amount="20.00" Name="D" Type="1" />
      <Product Amount="60.00" Name="E, G" Type="2" />
      <Product Amount="70.00" Name="F, H" Type="1" />
    </Products>
  </Location>
  <Location>
    <Products>
      <Product Amount="5.00" Name="I" Type="A" />
      <Product Amount="10.00" Name="J" Type="B" />
      <Product Amount="25.00" Name="K" Type="A" />
      <Product Amount="30.00" Name="L" Type="B" />
      <Product Amount="35.00" Name="M" Type="B" />
    </Products>
  </Location>
</Locations>
```

Comment: I don't think this problem is sufficiently well-defined. IIUC, you want each location to have at most 5 products, and route the excess products to one of the 5 according to type - is that correct? What if a location has more than 5 types of products? What if the first 5 products are all of the same type, but the remaining products are not?

Comment: For this example, the max I can output is 5 lines of `Product` data. Ideally, I would like to output them individually, but since there can be more than 5, I need to output as many individually as I can and group the rest based on `Type` to finish filling the container.